# OnLocationChanged method not working

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

this is my android activity code

```
public class driver_maps extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
String latitude,longitude,lat,lng,cmp,ID;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(GoogleServiceAvailable())
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Perfect!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_maps);
        Intent test=getIntent();
        latitude=test.getStringExtra("lat");
        longitude=test.getStringExtra("lng");
        cmp=test.getStringExtra("company");
        ID=test.getStringExtra("driverID");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Click on the map to activate the route",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        initMap();
    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.error);
    }
}
public boolean GoogleServiceAvailable()
{
    GoogleApiAvailability api=GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable=api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isAvailable== ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable))
    {
        Dialog dialog=api.getErrorDialog(this,isAvailable,0);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cant connect to play services",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}
private void initMap() {
    MapFragment mapFragment= (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    goToLocation(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude),15);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point)
        {
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng))).title("Origin.").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude))).title("Destination.").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
            LatLng origin = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng));
            LatLng dest = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
            // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
            String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
            Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
            FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();
            // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
            FetchUrl.execute(url);
        }
    });
}

public void goToLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
    LatLng ll=new LatLng(lat,lng);
    CameraUpdate update=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,zoom);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
    //mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title("Destination."));
}

private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


    return url;
}
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();
        Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            Log.d("ParserTask", jsonData[0].toString());
            DataParser parser = new DataParser();
            Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            Log.d("ParserTask", "Executing routes");
            Log.d("ParserTask", routes.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ParserTask", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }
    /////
    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(10);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

            Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");

        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if(lineOptions != null) {
            mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("onPostExecute","without Polylines drawn");
        }
    }
}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TEST TO SEE IF WORKING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    lat=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    lng=String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude "+lat+"         Longitude "+lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(driver_maps.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Updating Location Failed")
                            .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    UpdateLocation updateLocation=new UpdateLocation(cmp,ID,Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng),responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(driver_maps.this);
    queue.add(updateLocation);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}
}
```

It gives me an error at the line where I add the origin marker, I'm guessing it's caused by the fact that lat/lng values are null since the onlocationchanged didn't work
this is the stack trace on the runtime:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
                  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
                  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                  at com.example.omara.trackit.driver_maps$1.onMapClick(driver_maps.java:118)
```

Comment: i tried walking around the house for 1min before clicking on the map, since the app only crashes when i click on the map, anyway for the whole min the onlocationchanged didnt work at all

Comment: i'm sorry but that other answer nor ur comments here are the solutions to my code

Comment: what is your line 118 in your code? Please point out